# Gzip response from soapUI in PHP

Tags: groovy, compression, gzip, soapui

I m trying to get gzip response and for that I'm sending this node in body.

```
$body['TPA_Extensions']['IntelliSellTransaction']['CompressResponse']['Value'] = "true";
```

It returned successful response but didn't show it in `var_dump`. In `var_dump` it shows `Null`. In below image it shows successful response. [Successful Response Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qj6Y.jpg)

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I get this data "H4sIAAAAAAAAALWS0WvbMBDG/5VDe/BLbTkLY..."

Comment: Saleha, have you got chance to try the solution to see if that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

For the request test step, add `Script Assertion` with below snippet:

```
//Check response is not empty
assert context.response

//Parse response and fetch required value
def cResponse = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response).'**'.find {it.name() == 'CompressedResponse'}?.text()

log.info "Extracted data : $cResponse"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Rao but i'm using php. how to do this in php?

Comment: Thought you are using in SoapUI. No voice in php, sorry.